# Results Based on Date and Save as Finished

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm currently building a CMS/CRM system for my company using CodeIgniter, and I will need a way of displaying a list/table of results based upon whether an event has finished or not.

So, if the event start_date is in the past (based on the current timestamp), I need a way to dynamically set the 'active' column to 0 in the database, thus not showing the record.

How would you guys approach this problem? Would really appreciate your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as simple as you made your question to pull the list:

```
$data = $this->db->get_where('table',array('start_date <'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now'))))->result_array();
```

if you need to do an update to show that the event is done though:

```
$this->db->where('active >',0)->where('start_date <',date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('now')))->update('table',array('active'=>0));
```

that being, if the start_date column is a mysql timestamp. but regardless, it's as easy as it sounds.